Eyes movement problem
I have this problem related to the eye, My problem is when i move head the eyes not move so i made eyes bone parent to head then when i rotate the head the eyes rotate but not in correct rotation and the eyes control bone doesn't work. i have tried many ways but still same issue. so please check my file and if anyone have a solution please let me know.
thanks in advance

You need to explain what problem it is that you have. What may see obvious for you, knowning your own project, is impossible to guess for us.

hello, there's no image or text

Please share your file in the conventional way rather than requiring folks to ask for access.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it. You should also add images to demonstrate the problem you're having.

Don’t just give a punctuationless description of your problem and then wait for us to download a file. Add screenshots. Also, this sounds like three or four problems in one, and you’re not supposed to do that on stackexchange.

I explained my problem and uploaded the file, screenshot will not show anything its just an image, i am trying to upload video of the problem but i think not allowed in this website.

Sorry but by putting files on Google drive and then expecting folks to ask for access to them you're unlikely to get any help here!

I shared the file so anyone can download it without permission or asking @JohnEason

The link in your comment above is still requesting access here.

i updated with another link, pls download it from the main question @JohnEason

Ok. I'm no expert with rigging, but I'm not sure where you learned to rig those eyes. I suggest you follow this simple YT tutorial and then change it to your requirements later.

There are two problems to solve the issue:
1 - the eyes bones have to be child of head bone (in Edit mode, select the eyes bones, shift select the head bone (last) > Ctrl P > Keep Offset).
2 - Every eye mesh has a double parenting, resulting in double movement which brigs them out of place: one comes from the direct bone parenting, one comes from the armature modifier. To solve, delete the Armature modifier from both eyes mesh.

BTW, better use Damped track bone constraint instead of Track to, because it is more stable.

Thank you so much, i tried the first step before but i didn't ever think of double parenting @josh sanfelici

@Reem A if the answer is correct, mark it as such
